# Why pass python construct variables with default None?

Tags: python, class, oop, default

I see for defining a class in sqlalchemy, the popular pattern is to pass the variables of the User like name, password, email, etc. with default value None to the construct function.
But in other classes ( like posts of a blog ) they do not define default values.

so to clear : 
why defining default values and why None ?

Comment: So you don't have to supply all of them?

Comment: There's one common gotcha that is overcome by using `None` as a default parameter: [using mutable default arguments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few reasons you might want to use `None` as a default argument

## It is actually the default value you want

This is especially applicable to SqlAlchemy because you may have a database column with default value of `NULL`

## You want a mutable default value

Using a mutable default value such as a list can cause unpredictable behavior. You can provide a default value of `None` in order to change the scope of the mutable argument and avoid these issues.

## You want to force the use of keyword arguments

In python 2, the only way to force all arguments to be keywords is to define them as keyword arguments, with no positional arguments.